# receive data on calling same page html

Tags: javascript, html, get, query-string

I am new to HTML and JS . I want to retain the values of textbox and dropdown after pressing submit on same page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>    
    function tab()
    {
        //var t=document.getElementById("test").value;
        //document.getElementById("run").value = t;
    //t=> You send it to XML
    var test_a = document.getElementById("test");
    var selectedText = test_a.options[test_a.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("run").value = selectedText;
    }
</script>

<form name="myform" action="test.html" method="get">

<select id="test" onchange="tab()">

    <option value="-1">--select--</option>

    <option value="IN" >INDIA</option>

    <option value="BZ">BRAZIL</option>

</select>

<input type="text" name="run" id="run"/>

<input type="Submit">

 </form>

 </body>

 </html>
```

Comment: please show you html part also

Comment: What does "submit" do in this case?  If you have server-side code then that code can read the submitted values and re-populate the page with those values.

Comment: It's depend on your page if page is post back it is not possible..

Answer (score 0):

It will same, see in fiddle [`Here`](http://jsfiddle.net/cNDHv/2/)

Comment: now can you clearify what you want to do after click submit button

Comment: Thanx . And sorry for late acknowledgement